# About the differences between definitions of "Capable Group"

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, terminology, definition

I am looking for the properties of groups having "immediate Descendants", in other therm, "Capable Groups"; The problem that I fond is that "Capable Group" could have many meaning!

So, could you please help  me to optimize my "bibliographical" research?

I am using data bases like Mathscinet

Thank you very much

Comment: Just wikipedia: In mathematics, in the realm of group theory, a group is said to be **capable** if it occurs as the inner automorphism group of some group. Reference: R. Baer.See also the posts on this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073513/non-capable-groups-and-their-direct-products).

Comment: @DietrichBurde exactly Professor, also "if it is a central factor group", and "If it has immediate descendants"...; Are these equivalent definitions? They don´t seem so!

Comment: @DietrichBurde In fact the definition you gave me and "if it is a central factor group" can be seen easily as equivalent; The real problem is with "If it has immediate descendants"!

Comment: @DietrichBurde The idea is how to restrict my research on "capable groups of the definition "If it has immediate descendants"?

Comment: Yes, Hall has discussed these equivalent properties in his publication "The classification of prime-power groups" of 1940, page 137. A group is capable if it has immediate descendents.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You mean "finite group theory" the book of M.Hall?

Comment: No, the reference is to a paper by P. Hall (Philip Hall). The author of the book was Marshall Hall. They were not related.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Many thanks professor, this is really helpful.